# Populating JqueryMobile ListView from Json String

Tags: json, listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am trying to populate listview from JSON data but its not working -

**the Json**

```
{
    "reg": {
        "user": [{
            "LastEdited": "16 Apr 2014 03:18:25",
                "Picture": "\/storage\/sdcard0\/XLEZData\/XLEZ_Input\/Client\/22U2621210__PIN_Ver1.0\/image002.png",
                "Email": "adil@adil.com",
                "Name": "adil"
        }, {
            "LastEdited": "16 Apr 2014 03:18:55",
                "Picture": "\/storage\/sdcard0\/XLEZData\/XLEZ_Input\/Client\/22U2621210__PIN_Ver1.0\/image002.png",
                "Email": "adil",
                "Name": ""
        }, {
            "LastEdited": "24 Apr 2014 10:57:34",
                "Picture": "\/storage\/sdcard0\/Pictures\/Screenshots\/Screenshot_2013-07-11-14-33-35.png",
                "Email": "test@s3.com",
                "Name": "s3 test"
        }]
    }
}
```

I have this list in native android like this

[image]

How can i make this in jQueryMobile ?

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vyR9L/

Comment: @Omar : i have tried to make it in JS function because i have to call it in native android activity which will send json string to this function i have made a demo using your code , kindly see whats the mistake  http://jsfiddle.net/5BKAA/1/

Comment: wrap code in `head` and remove `)` at the end of the function http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5BKAA/2/